# Bringing PNG as an icon

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular2-routing

Hi I have the code for simple nav between by pages.

```
<super-tabs tabsPlacement="top" toolbarBackground="3D9BDD" toolbarColor="dark" indicatorColor="light"
(tabSelect)="onTabSelect($event)">
<super-tab *ngFor="let page of pages" [class]="page.class" [root]="page.pageName" [icon]="page.icon" [id]="page.id"></super-tab>
```

I need now to switch the icon to PNGs like:

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

and butter as a circle buttons.

Wish for help!

Comment: Does you need to stick to **.png** file format? Or you just wanna make that image as icon?

Comment: @HyuckKang I want to make the images for icons (3) I tried with:                                             `ion-icon {
   /* &[class*="before-"] {
        // Instead of using the font-based icons
        // We're applying SVG masks
        mask-size: contain;
        mask-position: 50% 50%;
        mask-repeat: no-repeat;
        background: currentColor;
        width: 1em;
        height: 1em;
    }
   
 &[class*="before-icon"] {
    mask-image: url(../assets/icon/Stage11.sgv);` but didn't work.. so can I add 3 buttons like this as tabs?

Comment: Sorry, what you mentioned is what I would like to recommend.

Comment: @HyuckKang thank you :) now I see that I am having a problem with every path of image.. it does not find anything (vs code)